# Syncing Data in a partially referenced google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a spreadsheet linked to an apps script project. I have a master sheet that keeps the names of students, it is populated via an API call. I reference **parts** of the master sheet on other sheets in the same spreadsheet such as a student's name.

In the other sheets, I keep grades that use a reference from the master sheet to add the name of the student to the grading sheet, but the grades are added manually in the row as I grade. [Here is an example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FqGgfXdIkW0nK089-fK-vz6rChRR81f00VwtCtR8454/edit?usp=sharing).

However, I am finding it extremely difficult to keep the master sheet in sync with my other sheets. If I sort the Master sheet, the referenced values are sorted on the referenced sheet, but this throws the grades off since they aren't sorted when the master sheet is sorted.

In addition, when I make an API call, if a student is added to the class, removed, or both (a few students added and a few students drop out) the partially referenced sheets with grades become misaligned.

I am adding logic into my spreadsheet to insert rows and remove rows to keep the master sheet in sync with my partially referenced grade sheet, but I'm finding the logic to do this tedious and difficult.

Am I missing something obvious? I don't have a lot of spreadsheet experience, I have javascript experience, but I feel like I am missing something simple to keep the partially referenced rows in sync (this is the desired behavior).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Can you please provide the code in question? Also since you try to keep the rows in sync have you tried making use of [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)?